# Pandas-Insert a first row with sum of a column and then use the previous value-LAG of column

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have the data like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"MONTHS":[1,2,3,4,5,6], "METRIC":[430,584,648,571,610,535]})
```

df = pd.DataFrame({"MONTHS":[1,2,3,4,5,6], "METRIC":[430,584,648,571,610,535]})
what I want to do is find the sum of the metric column =3378

```
 MONTHS  METRIC                     MONTHS NEW_METRIC            NEW_METRIC
 1          430                      0       3378                 sum of METRIC
 2          584                      1       3378                 sum of METRIC
 3          648        -->           2       2948     explain  previous value-lag of metric(3378-430)
 4          571                      3       2364              previous value-lag of metric(2948-584)    
 5          610                      4       1716              =2364-648
 6          535                      5       1145              =1716-571
                                     6       535               =1145-535
```

So here basically created a new row with 0 added and the corresponding new metric is the sum and for value 1 it is also the sum for new metric but from month=2 it should subtract the lag value of metric with previous row value of the same column (3378-430) and similiarly for months3 it would be (2948-584) month4 is (2364-648)etc till the end. I used the following code.

```
df["METRIC"].sum() - df["METRIC"].reindex(np.arange(0, 7)).shift(2).fillna(0)
```

but I want the first two values to be sum but later it should take the previous value -df["METRIC"].reindex(np.arange(0, 7)).shift(2).fillna(0). From the months 3 the new metric fails as I need to use previous value instead of sum of metric. How do I correct it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can subtract by the cumulative sum.

---

```
df.METRIC.sum() - df.METRIC.reindex(np.arange(df.shape[0]+1)).shift(2).cumsum().fillna(0)
```

```
0    3378.0
1    3378.0
2    2948.0
3    2364.0
4    1716.0
5    1145.0
6     535.0
Name: METRIC, dtype: float64
```